# Cant Login to intranet sites after windows update March 11 2015

Tags: windows, iis

Can anyone help ?
After Windows Update yesterday we cannot login to our intranet sites
From Windows 7 pc's.
Only from Windows XP access is enabled

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove from the Domain Controller security update KB3002657.